# AWS Appsync Graphql get query returns error when giving empty input

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I've built an Appsync GraphQL API with CDK v2. Everything is deployed and looks fine.

In the query tool in the AppSync console I tried to build a getUsers query:

```
query MyQueryNonSpecific {
  getUsers(getUsersInput: {}) {
    data {
      country
      email
      firstName
    }
    nextToken
  }
```

But it returns the following:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getUsers": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getUsers"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "string",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 22,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "handled"
```

However if I populate the getUsersInput parameter with a primary key:

```
getUsersInput: {email: "oaijsd@eegmail.com"}
```

Then I get the expected result. So the lambda resolver is hooked up correctly, it's just that smth goes wrong when the getUsersInput is empty...

Here is my schema:

```
type GetUsersResponse {
    data: [User];
    nextToken: String;
}

input GetUsersInput {
    email: String;
    nextToken: String;
}

# Queries
type Query {
    getUsers(getUsersInput: GetUsersInput!): GetUsersResponse
}
```

And here is my lambda resolver:

```
type Result = {
  data: User[];
  nextToken: string;
};

export const handler: AppSyncResolverHandler<GetUsersParams, Result> = async (event, context) => {
  return new Promise<Result>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      // Print Event
      utils.logInfo(event, 'Event');
      
      // Get DDB DocClient
      const ddbDocClient = await utils.getDDBDocClient();

      // Query command input with attributes to get 
      const queryCommandInput: QueryCommandInput = {
        TableName: process.env.DDB_TABLE,
        ExclusiveStartKey: event.arguments.getUsersInput.nextToken 
          ? JSON.parse(Buffer.from(event.arguments.getUsersInput.nextToken, "base64").toString("ascii")) 
          : undefined,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {},
      };

      // Add Query Expression 
      if (event.arguments.getUsersInput.email) { // if email was included query on email
        queryCommandInput.KeyConditionExpression = "email = :email";
        queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
          ... queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues,
          ":email": event.arguments.getUsersInput.email,
        };
      } else { // if email not included query on itemType
        queryCommandInput.IndexName = "itemType-index";
        queryCommandInput.KeyConditionExpression = "itemType = :itemType",
        queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
          ... queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues,
          "itemType": "User",
        };
      }

      // Execute Query
      const queryCommandOutput = await ddbDocClient.send(new QueryCommand(queryCommandInput));
      const result: Result = {
        data: queryCommandOutput.Items ? (queryCommandOutput.Items as User[]): [],
        nextToken: queryCommandOutput.LastEvaluatedKey
        ? Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(queryCommandOutput.LastEvaluatedKey)).toString("base64")
        : ""
      };

      // return result
      resolve(result);

    } catch (error: any) {
      utils.logError(error);
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, in ExpressionAttributeValues in the else block of the lambda resolver I forgot to prefix itemType with a colon:

```
queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues = {
          ... queryCommandInput.ExpressionAttributeValues,
          ":itemType": "User",
        };
```